# Not getting `.pc` files when installing packages in Alpine Linux

Tags: vlc, alpine-linux, alpine-package-keeper

When I am installing libraries in my Alpine 3.17 based docker container, I am not getting any of the `.pc` files that belongs to `pkg-config`. This makes compiling things that relies on those files to work difficult. The only `.pc` file I been able to get was luas, due to it supporting the command `add apk pc:lua`

```
$ pkg-config --list-all
lua5.2                         Lua - An Extensible Extension Language
shared-mime-info               shared-mime-info - Freedesktop common MIME database
```

As an example, I am trying to compile a Rust programm that relies on OpenSSL and VLC, and I get the erros:

```
run pkg_config fail: `PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "openssl"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
error: could not find system library 'openssl' required by the 'openssl-sys' crate

--- stderr
Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'openssl', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

```
--- stderr
Package libvlc was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvlc.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libvlc', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

However, both of them are install via the `add apk` command:

```
$ apk info vlc
vlc-3.0.18-r1 description:
A multi-platform MPEG, VCD/DVD, and DivX player

vlc-3.0.18-r1 webpage:
https://www.videolan.org/vlc/

vlc-3.0.18-r1 installed size:
15 MiB
```

```
$ apk info openssl
openssl-3.0.8-r4 description:
Toolkit for Transport Layer Security (TLS)

openssl-3.0.8-r4 webpage:
https://www.openssl.org/

openssl-3.0.8-r4 installed size:
868 KiB
```

Any idea how to fix it, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since those are files needed to compile libraries, they tend to be in the corresponding `*-dev` packages.

This said, you can always [use the website of Alpine Linux](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents) in order to find in which package a file that is erroring is contained in.

So, in your case:

- [*openssl.pc*](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=openssl.pc&path=&name=&branch=v3.17) is contained in the package `openssl-dev`
- [*libvlc.pc*](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=libvlc.pc&path=&name=&branch=v3.17) is contained in the package `vlc-dev`